# Can I use #springMessage in a Jade template

Tags: html, spring, pug

Is it possible to use #springMessage in a Jade template?
How? (What is the markup?)
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Message can be obtained by calling `RequestContext.getMessage()`, and `RequestContext` can be exposed as a request attribute by setting `exposeSpringMacroHelpers` to `true` in [`AbstractTemplateView`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/AbstractTemplateView.html).